# Get value from input tags in JS with no id or HTML control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

The HTML in this project is generated by a parsing system. so I have no control over the HTML. However i can add javascript or jquery.

The HTML looks somthing like:

```
<div class="input-group" id="userList">
  <span ../>
  <ul class="accepted-suggestions">
     <li><div class="user">...</div>
         <input type="hidden" value="myUserName1"></input>
     </li>
     <li><div class="user">...</div>
         <input type="hidden" value="myUserName1"></input>
     </li>
     <li as many list elements as the user is selecting>
      .......
     </li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

In the HTML the ul list gets populated as the logged in user choose users to add to the list. How can I access the hidden input values which was added in this list in jquery? note that I can not add anything to the HTML.

Comment: When you know the exact document structure, you can navigate through the DOM tree.

Use the `document.getElementsByClassName('accepted-suggestions')` function to get to your `<ul>` tag and from there navigate to the respective `childNodes` to get to your inputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you haven't mentioned what to do with them after accessing

```
 $( ".accepted-suggestions" ).find( "li input[type='hidden']" ).each( function(){

    alert( $(this).val() );

    });
```

Comment: damn, beat me to it. Was writing almost exactly the same :D

Answer (score 1):

I have used your code in the example:

working [JSFIDDE](http://jsfiddle.net/00esyw4t/2/)

here is html code:

```
<div class="input-group" id="userList">
  <span ../>
  <ul class="accepted-suggestions">
     <li><div class="user">...</div>
         <input type="hidden" value="myUserName1">
     </li>
     <li><div class="user">...</div>
         <input type="hidden" value="myUserName1">
     </li>
     <li as many list elements as the user is selecting>
      .......
     </li>
  </ul>  
</div>
```

jquery code:

```
var li_objs = $('ul.accepted-suggestions').find('li');
var input_objs = $('ul.accepted-suggestions').find('input');
alert(li_objs.length);

alert(input_objs.length);

input_objs.each(function (i,input_obj) {
    alert($(input_obj).attr('value'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

does it have name value ? The you could use:

```
onclick="execute(document.getElementsByName('textbox1')[0].value)
```

OR

```
var inputs, index; inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input'); 
for (index = 0; index < inputs.length; ++index) {

// deal with inputs[index] element.}
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript
Check the type property of the **`document.getElementsByTagName("input")`** and see if it's hidden.
So:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
//loop for all the x values
for(var i=0;i<=x.length;i++){
var type=x[i].type // see if it is hidden.

}
```